# Как работать с QAxObject в отдельном потоке?

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word

**Пытаюсь сгенерировать документ word в отдельном потоке:**

```
wordApp_ = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
wordDoc_ = wordApp_->querySubObject("Documents()");
newDoc_ = wordDoc_->querySubObject("Add()");
newDoc_->querySubObject("PageSetup")->setProperty("Orientation", "wdOrientLandscape");

rangeInputData_ = newDoc_->querySubObject("Range()");
rangeInputData_->dynamicCall("SetRange(int, int)", 0, 100);

font_rangeInputData_ = rangeInputData_->querySubObject("Font");
font_rangeInputData_->setProperty("Size", 14);
font_rangeInputData_->setProperty("Name", "Times New Roman");

tables_ = newDoc_->querySubObject("Tables()");
rangeTable_ = newDoc_->querySubObject("Range()");
rangeTable_->dynamicCall("SetRange(int, int)", 201, 300);
table_ = tables_->querySubObject("Add(Range, NumRows, NumColumns, DefaultTableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior)",
                                                rangeTable_->asVariant(), numRows_ + 1, numColumns_, 1, 1);
```

**Выводит ошибки:**

*QAxBase::setControl: requested control Word.Application could not be instantiated*

*QAxBase::dynamicCallHelper: Object is not initialized, or initialization failed*

**P.S**

В одном потоке все работает отлично, но когда я создаю документ, то подвисает пользовательский интерфейс. Именно поэтому я хотел бы вывести эту задачу в другой поток. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Подключил `"window.h"`

Добавил код перед вызовом функции:

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
```